# Problem related to finding the PDF of a function of some random variable

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Problem related to finding the probability density function (PDF) in terms of another RV (Finding PDF of a function of a random variable). Unsure where to start.

Determine the probability density function of $Y$ where,

$$Y = \frac{X}{\left(6-X\right)}$$

where $X$ is a random variable with uniform distribution over $\left(1,6\right)$.

Comment: There is no information on what the problem is here.

Comment: $$ Y <y   ,   X < y (6 -X)  , X (1+y) < 6 y,  X < \frac{6 y}{1+y}  $$ if the two X's represent the same  event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, we have two random variables $X$ and $Y$. $Y$ is a function of $X$. The PDF of $X$ is known, and we need to find the PDF of $Y$. Let me first state a theorem (without proof) using which we can achieve this.

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with support $S_X$ and PDF $f_X(x)$. Suppose that $S_X$ is a finite union of disjoint open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ and let $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Borel function such that $h$ is differentiable and strictly monotone on $S_X$. Then $Y = h(X)$ is a continuous random variable with support $S_Y = \{h(x):x\in S_X\}$ and PDF:
$$
f_Y(y) =
    \begin{cases}
        f_X(h^{-1}(y)) \cdot |\frac{d}{dy}h^{-1}(y)|, & \text{if } y \in S_Y\\
        0, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
$$

$$$$
Here, the random variable $X$ is uniformly distributed over $(1,6)$. So, the PDF of $X$ is:
$$
f_X(x) =
    \begin{cases}
        \frac{1}{5}, & \text{if } x \in (1,6)\\
        0, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
$$
The support of $X$, $S_X = (1,6)$.

The function $h$ here is $$h(x)=\frac{x}{6-x}$$
which is a Borel function, and hence $Y=h(X)$ is a random variable, to start with.

Clearly, $h(x)$ is differentiable and strictly monotone on $S_X$. Now, the support of $Y$ is, $$S_Y = h(S_X) = (\frac{1}{5}, \infty)$$

Also, $$h^{-1}(y) = \frac{6y}{1+y}$$
Using the above-mentioned theorem, we have:

$$
f_Y(y) =
    \begin{cases}
        f_X(\frac{6y}{1+y}) \cdot |\frac{6}{1+y^2}|, & \text{if } y \in (\frac{1}{5}, \infty)\\ 0, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
$$

$$
=
    \begin{cases}
        \frac{1}{5} \cdot \frac{6}{1+y^2}, & \text{if } y \in (\frac{1}{5}, \infty)\\ 0, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
$$
And this is precisely the PDF of the random variable $Y$.